# jmeter jdbc request parameter type

Tags: jmeter

I am constructing a jmeter jdbc Prepared Select statement request.
I have the query as,

```
select * from tableName where c=?

Parameter Value: ${columnId}
Parameter Type: LONGVARCHAR
```

When I run I get a: type mismatch error UNSIGNED_LONG and CHAR for c='1234'

I need to pass a long value here. Also, how would I pass a binary array?

Comment: try with BIGINT. reference http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html

Comment: @Naveen how would I pass a binary ? I have a byte Array that needs to be passed to the query as a BINARY type.

Comment: What is the datatype that is defined in sql table schema for that param??

Answer (score 2):

You should use **User defined variables** as reference. This way you can avid using Parameter fields.

Reference: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html

```html
select * from tableName where c='${columnId}'
```